# What is this gorgeous bicolor-leaved ornamental plant?

Tags: identification

I found this plant in a public space in Belgrade, Serbia:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, there is also a white flowered variant nearby:

[image]

[image]

What is it?

EDIT: I shortly realized it is Gaura. But, what exact cultivar (this is crucial)?